# ModalupDialog not Working Properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, modal-dialog

i had made Modalupdialog for Document Upload fro following Cod.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectUpload() {


        var tempUrl = "/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={1264ADD5-41C8-4DF8-8468-BF275EA55E3E}";

        var options = {
            url: tempUrl,
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
            title: "Upload",
            allowMaximize: true,
            showClose: true,
            //dialogReturnValueCallback: showModalDialog
        };

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
</Script>
```

But. it Display Blank Dialog for Second & Disapper.I am Calling this function from onclientclick of Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done by taking Html Button instead of Asp.net Button.

Answer (score 0):

The comma after showClose must be deleted, you have commented the dialogReturnValueCallback and therefor the comma must be removed.

1. What happens when you add the url to the browseraddress?
2. Change the script to window.location = tempUrl to see if your url is correct

Comment: Thanks bonm...
But,This is not the Reason.